# União de dois selects que apresentam em linha

Tags: sql, oracle, select

Abaixo, segue uma consulta realizada para banco de dados ORACLE:

```
SELECT
ITOS.CD_NUMERO_OS,
ITOS.DESCRICAO_RECLA AS "DEFEITO APRESENTADO"

FROM GMITEMOS ITOS

INNER JOIN GMOSERVI OS ON OS.CD_NUMERO_OS = ITOS.CD_NUMERO_OS
INNER JOIN GMITEMOS IT ON IT.CD_NUMERO_OS = ITOS.CD_NUMERO_OS

WHERE OS.DT_OS BETWEEN TO_DATE(:data_os_inicial, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE(:data_os_final, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
AND OS.SITUACAO LIKE 'E'
AND IT.TIPO_OS LIKE '3'

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT
ITOS.CD_NUMERO_OS,
SL.DESCRICAO_SOLUC AS "SOLUCAO DO DEFEITO"

FROM GMITEMOS ITOS

INNER JOIN GMOSERVI OS ON OS.CD_NUMERO_OS = ITOS.CD_NUMERO_OS
INNER JOIN GMITEMOS IT ON IT.CD_NUMERO_OS = ITOS.CD_NUMERO_OS
INNER JOIN GMDETALH SL ON SL.CD_NUMERO_OS = ITOS.CD_NUMERO_OS

WHERE OS.DT_OS BETWEEN TO_DATE(:data_os_inicial, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE(:data_os_final, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
AND OS.SITUACAO LIKE 'E'
AND IT.TIPO_OS LIKE '3'
```

Segue abaixo um PRINT de como as informações estão sendo entregues em tela:
[image: Resultado da consulta citada acima]

Como podemos observar, é apresentado um DEFEITO e logo após uma SOLUÇÃO para o mesmo nº de OS(CD_NUMERO_OS).
Por exemplo na OS com CD_NUMERO_OS = 860, o item 1 da grade é um DEFEITO e o item 2 é uma SOLUÇÃO.
Preciso exibir o DEFEITO E SOLUÇÃO lado a lado, exibir em formato de colunas e não em linhas conforme o print acima.

Alguma idéia de como posso exibir esse resultado lado a lado???

**Detalhe: A OS com CD_NUMERO_OS = 866 aparece 3 vezes um DEFEITO e 3 vezes uma SOLUÇÃO por que a mesma OS possui 3 itens diferentes.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reescreva seu select desta forma:

```
SELECT
    
ITOS.CD_NUMERO_OS,
ITOS.DESCRICAO_RECLA AS "DEFEITO APRESENTADO",
NVL(SL.DESCRICAO_SOLUC, 'NAO RESOLVIDO') AS "SOLUCAO DO DEFEITO"

FROM GMITEMOS ITOS,    
GMOSERVI OS,
GMITEMOS IT, 
GMDETALH SL

WHERE OS.DT_OS BETWEEN TO_DATE(:data_os_inicial, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE(:data_os_final, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
AND OS.CD_NUMERO_OS = ITOS.CD_NUMERO_OS
AND IT.CD_NUMERO_OS = ITOS.CD_NUMERO_OS
AND IT.ITEM = ITOS.ITEM /* faltou esse */
AND SL.CD_NUMERO_OS(+) = ITOS.CD_NUMERO_OS
AND OS.SITUACAO LIKE 'E'
AND IT.TIPO_OS LIKE '3'
```

Eu prefiro usar equijoins, pois já vi casos (principalmente em SQL montado pelo EntityFramework da plataforma .NET) que com inner join fica mais lento, mas aí vc pode fazer um comparativo e ver qual forma é melhor.

Veja que para relacionar a tabela `SL` eu usei o operador (+) que indica um `LEFT JOIN`, pois um defeito pode não ter sido resolvido

Comment: nota: a OS 866 vai aparecer a mesma solução 3 vezes, porque a solução é por OS e não por item

Comment: Funcionou muito bem amigo, muito obrigado!
Mas olha só, preciso que apareça apenas 1 defeito e 1 solução por item da OS, como citei anteriormente a OS 866 possui 3 itens, portanto 3 defeitos e 3 soluções.
Segue abaixo o resultado retornado para seguinte consulta. 
Tem ideia de como posso solucionar mais esse "problema" ai?? rsrs @JMSlasher

Comment: cara acho que só faltou o relacionamento da tabela de item `IT` com a a tabela de item da OS `ITOS`

Comment: pergunta ITOS e IT estão relacionando a mesma tabela, acredito que dê apenas para referenciar a tabela `ITOS` e omitir `IT`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    
ITOS.CD_NUMERO_OS,
ITOS.ITEM AS "ITEM DA OS",
ITOS.DESCRICAO_RECLA AS "DEFEITO APRESENTADO",
NVL(SL.DESCRICAO_SOLUC, 'NAO RESOLVIDO') AS "SOLUCAO DO DEFEITO"

FROM GMITEMOS ITOS,    
GMOSERVI OS,
GMITEMOS IT, 
GMDETALH SL

WHERE OS.DT_OS BETWEEN TO_DATE(:data_os_inicial, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE(:data_os_final, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
AND OS.CD_NUMERO_OS = ITOS.CD_NUMERO_OS
AND IT.CD_NUMERO_OS = ITOS.CD_NUMERO_OS
AND SL.CD_NUMERO_OS(+) = ITOS.CD_NUMERO_OS
AND OS.SITUACAO LIKE 'E'
AND IT.TIPO_OS LIKE '3'

ORDER BY itos.cd_numero_os ASC, itos.item ASC
```

Segue o print do resultado.
[image: Resultado da consulta citada acima]

Comment: Isto é uma resposta ou um complemento da pergunta? Se não for uma solução do problema então está no lugar errado, deveria ter editado a pergunta e acrescentado o complemento.